# log4j2 KeyValuePair for .properties file

Tags: properties, log4j2

How do I create a keyvaluepair in log4j2 in a propterties file?

I know in log4j version 1 it's done like:

```
log4j.appender.x.additionalFields={'key': 'value'}
```

and the XML way for it in log4j2 is:

```
  <KeyValuePair key="key" value="value"/>
```

so is way to do it for a properties file like this:

```
`appender.x.keyValuePair ={'key': 'value'}`
```

?

Answer (score 9):

This is a working example of how to define a key value pair for example for the Graylog2 (GELF) appender:

```
appender.graylog.type=GELF
appender.graylog.name=GRAYLOG
appender.graylog.server=yourhostname
appender.graylog.includeStackTrace=true
appender.graylog.additional1.type=KeyValuePair
appender.graylog.additional1.key=yarncontainer
appender.graylog.additional1.value=containerXYZ
appender.graylog.additional2.type=KeyValuePair
appender.graylog.additional2.key=anotherKey
appender.graylog.additional2.value=anotherValue
```

Comment: Any ideas how to add more than just one field?

Comment: That's really the holy grail here. Sadly, I was never able to find out how to do that :(

Comment: I managed to get it without "additionalFields" part - used just "additional1", "additional2" - final result got merged. I did not inspect why it works but it does.

Comment: I updated the example, I also needed to add multiple fields and verified that it works like that

Comment: I was looking at for the flink logj2 configuration file. Thank you Robert and Scolytus